# Assigning Thumbnails via Magento REST API

Tags: product-images, rest-api, image-upload, thumbnail, gallery-image

I am trying to add thumbnail images to SKUs via REST API. However, the image is added but does not show as a thumbnail. Please see my POST request below

https://url.co.uk/rest/V1/products/231877/media

```
  "entry": {
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "test",
    "position": 0,
    "disabled": false,
    "types": [
       "thumbnail","small_image"
    ],
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "myencodeddata",
   "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "test"
    },
    "extension_attributes": {
    }
  }
}

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Are you uploading image of type jpeg?

Comment: Hi @RahulBarot yes it is a jpeg image. It adds the image to the product detail page in Magento admin but not as a thumbnail

Comment: I then need to go into the product and assign the image role as thumbnail. Can I not assign this role straight away in the API?